# jQuery Datatable - How to delete a row using cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I want to search a cell in my JQuery datatable which has the content of var x and delete the row which contains the cell.

I tried this:

```
function deletedatarow(){
      var x = "tzr";
      $( "tr:contains('" + x + "')").fnDeleteRow();
};
```

but it doesnt work.

Can anyone tell me why and help me to find a solution?

Comment: It seems to be working if I change `fnDeleteRow()` to `hide()`: http://jsfiddle.net/FJVH9/1/ -- I don't think this snippet of code is your problem.

Comment: Thank you, this was the half solution, i had a part of wrong code in my javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referring to the jQuery DataTables plugin, then you're doing it wrong, your code should look something like this:

```
// Set oDatatables variable somewhere above this line..    
function deletedatarow(){
  var x = "tzr";
  $( "tr:contains('" + x + "')").each(function() {
    oDatatables.fnDeleteRow(this);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using plain tables. there are many j!uery plugins available. like

http://datatables.net/ it provides easy api of table manipulations.

Comment: If you look tho the "$" you will see that I use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

```
function deletedatarow() 
    {
    var oData = $('#Testtable').dataTable();
    var x = "tzr";
    $( "tr:contains('" + x + "')").each(function() 
        {
        oData.fnDeleteRow(this);
        });
    };
```